# Swift - Autolayout constraints UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to do UI programatically and I'm getting weird constraint errors, but when I run the app, it it looks as expected.

[image]

**What I'm trying to do:**

I have a ViewController `TodayVC` where I have a `UIView` and I'm trying to render content of `MWStepsActivityVC` in that view.

**Here is my TodayVC:**

```
class TodayVC: UIViewController {
    
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let contentView = UIView()
    
    let stepsActivityView = UIView()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureViewController()
        configureScrollView()
        configureContainerViews()
        layoutUI()
    }
    
    func configureViewController() {
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }
    
    func configureScrollView() {
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        scrollView.pinToEdges(of: view)
        contentView.pinToEdges(of: scrollView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
            contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 600)
        ])
    }
    
    func configureContainerViews() {
        self.add(childVC: MWStepsActivityVC(activityType: .steps), to: self.stepsActivityView)
    }
    
    func layoutUI() {
        contentView.addSubview(stepsActivityView)
        stepsActivityView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let padding: CGFloat = 20
        let itemHeight: CGFloat = 140
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stepsActivityView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            stepsActivityView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            stepsActivityView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: padding),
            stepsActivityView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: itemHeight),
        ])
        
        print("TodayVC view width \(view.frame.size.width)")
    }
    
    func add(childVC: UIViewController, to containerView: UIView) {
        addChild(childVC)
        containerView.addSubview(childVC.view)
        childVC.view.frame = containerView.bounds
        childVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

**UIViewExtension:**

```
extension UIView {
    func addSubviews(_ views: UIView...) {
        for view in views {
            addSubview(view)
        }
    }
    
    func pinToEdges(of superview: UIView) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor),
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor),
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.trailingAnchor),
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

**MWStepsActivityVC:**

```
class MWActivityVC: UIViewController {
    
    let iconImageView = UIImageView()
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let counterLabel = UILabel()
    
    init(activityType: ActivityType) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.set(activityType: activityType)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureBackgroundView()
        layoutUI()
        placeholderData()
    }
    
    fileprivate func placeholderData() {
        iconImageView.image = SFSymbols.steps
        titleLabel.text = "StepsStepsStepsStepsStepsStepsStepsStepsStepsStepsStepsStepsStepsStepsStepsStepsStepsSteps"
        counterLabel.text = "9000"
        counterLabel.backgroundColor = .red
    }
    
    fileprivate func configureBackgroundView() {
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 18
    }

    
    fileprivate func layoutUI() {
        view.addSubviews(iconImageView, titleLabel, counterLabel)
        iconImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        counterLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let padding: CGFloat = 20
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            iconImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: padding),
            iconImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            iconImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            iconImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            
            titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconImageView.centerYAnchor),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: padding),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            
            counterLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding),
            counterLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            counterLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            counterLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        ])
        
        print("MWStepsActivityVC view width \(view.frame.size.width)")
    }
}
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002228320 H:|-(20)-[UIImageView:0x7fc0abe077a0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fc0abd10850 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022283c0 UIImageView:0x7fc0abe077a0.width == 20   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002228460 H:[UIImageView:0x7fc0abe077a0]-(20)-[UILabel:0x7fc0abe08a70]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022284b0 UILabel:0x7fc0abe08a70.trailing == UIView:0x7fc0abd10850.trailing - 20   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002230b90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fc0abd10850.width == 0   (active)>",

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002228320 H:|-(20)-[UIImageView:0x7fc0abe077a0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fc0abd10850 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002228460 H:[UIImageView:0x7fc0abe077a0]-(20)-[UILabel:0x7fc0abe08a70]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022284b0 UILabel:0x7fc0abe08a70.trailing == UIView:0x7fc0abd10850.trailing - 20   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002230b90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fc0abd10850.width == 0   (active)>",


"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022285a0 H:|-(20)-[UILabel:0x7fc0abe08ce0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fc0abd10850 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022285f0 UILabel:0x7fc0abe08ce0.trailing == UIView:0x7fc0abd10850.trailing - 20   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002230b90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fc0abd10850.width == 0   (active)>"
```

I tried to use the [wtfautolayout.com](https://www.wtfautolayout.com/?constraintlog=%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002228320%20H:%7C-(20)-%5BUIImageView:0x7fc0abe077a0%5D%20%20%20(active,%20names:%20%27%7C%27:UIView:0x7fc0abd10850%20)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022283c0%20UIImageView:0x7fc0abe077a0.width%20%3D%3D%2020%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002228460%20H:%5BUIImageView:0x7fc0abe077a0%5D-(20)-%5BUILabel:0x7fc0abe08a70%5D%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022284b0%20UILabel:0x7fc0abe08a70.trailing%20%3D%3D%20UIView:0x7fc0abd10850.trailing%20-%2020%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002230b90%20%27UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width%27%20UIView:0x7fc0abd10850.width%20%3D%3D%200%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002228320%20H:%7C-(20)-%5BUIImageView:0x7fc0abe077a0%5D%20%20%20(active,%20names:%20%27%7C%27:UIView:0x7fc0abd10850%20)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002228460%20H:%5BUIImageView:0x7fc0abe077a0%5D-(20)-%5BUILabel:0x7fc0abe08a70%5D%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022284b0%20UILabel:0x7fc0abe08a70.trailing%20%3D%3D%20UIView:0x7fc0abd10850.trailing%20-%2020%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002230b90%20%27UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width%27%20UIView:0x7fc0abd10850.width%20%3D%3D%200%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022285a0%20H:%7C-(20)-%5BUILabel:0x7fc0abe08ce0%5D%20%20%20(active,%20names:%20%27%7C%27:UIView:0x7fc0abd10850%20)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x6000022285f0%20UILabel:0x7fc0abe08ce0.trailing%20%3D%3D%20UIView:0x7fc0abd10850.trailing%20-%2020%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002230b90%20%27UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width%27%20UIView:0x7fc0abd10850.width%20%3D%3D%200%20%20%20(active)%3E%22) website to understand what's wrong, and it seems the issue is with `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width` it thinks it's set to 0, but when I try to print `view.frame.size.width` I get correct width:

```
MWStepsActivityVC view width 375.0
TodayVC view width 375.0
```

Can someone help me with it? I'm struggling with this for a day already.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to fix it. I forgot to run `configureContainerViews` on main thread...

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.configureContainerViews()
}
```